# Set different Viewport Shading to each Collection

Tags: 3d-view

If I were to be in a case where I need one collection to be in Wireframe and another to be in Material Preview, how would I go about it? Is there an add-on or is it already implemented?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's any native automated way to do this per Collection. You can <kbd>Shift+G</kbd> *> Collection* to quickly select all objects in the same collection, then while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> select *Wireframe* from *Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display As*. Instead of holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you could also right click and press *Copy to Selected*.

Note that these wireframes are overlays and as such they're only for viewport shading, they won't show up in render outputs. If you're using Cycles for viewport rendering, you would also have to tick off *Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility > Camera*, and that *would* also affect the render output (objects with *Ray Visibility > Camera* ticked off won't show up in renders).

[image]

Comment: Note that this only sets the "maximum" level.  You have to have the viewport level set at the highest level you want to view.

Comment: @MartyFouts What do you mean by "viewport level"?

Comment: The "Viewport Shading" Method you set by picking from the last 4 icons in the 3D Viewport top bar.  If you set that to wireframe you're going to get wireframe for everything no matter what the "Viewport Display" is set to.  That said, your answer is the best one can do, as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, "level" threw me off. You're right, of course, this works for Material Preview and Render modes, and if render mode is employing Cycles you need to turn off "Camera" under Visibility > Ray Visibility as well (which I added to the answer).